# Fill NaN with the longest length column's values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to fill `v5` column's NaN with its longest length (by position from left side) not NaN columns' values.

```
     v1   v2   v3    v4     v5
0     a   ab  abc  abcd  abcde
1  abcd  abc   ab   NaN    NaN
2     a  abc   ac   cde    NaN
3   cde    c  NaN    cd    NaN
```

For example, for the second row of `v5`, its its longest length `Not NaN` column is `v1`, then we take `abcd`. If multiple values with the same longest length exist, then the value far left has priority, as example in the third row, we take `abc` as value of `v5` instead of `cde`.

Is it possible to do that in Pandas? Thanks.

The expected output is like this:

```
     v1   v2   v3    v4     v5
0     a   ab  abc  abcd  abcde
1  abcd  abc   ab   NaN   abcd
2     a  abc   ac   cde    abc
3   cde    c  NaN    cd    cde
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is test lengths of all values by [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html), then replace rows by missing values with no maximal rows by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), back filling missing values and last get first column by position:

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.len())

df['v5'] = df.where(df1.eq(df1.max(axis=1), axis=0)).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
     v1   v2   v3    v4     v5
0     a   ab  abc  abcd  abcde
1  abcd  abc   ab   NaN   abcd
2     a  abc   ac   cde    abc
3   cde    c  NaN    cd    cde
```

Comment: Thank you, if the value far right has priority, what I should modify in your code?

Comment: @ahbon - Then use `df['v5'] = df.where(df1.eq(df1.max(axis=1), axis=0)).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]`